# Android Google In-app-purchases v6 restore purchases without custom server

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I have implemented Google `In-app-purchases v6+` library. The user is able to purchase non-consumable virtual item.

When the user re-installs the app or installs the app on the another device with the same GMAIL the app must recover purchased item. But it does not happen. The `billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(params: QueryPurchasesParams)` returns empty list of purchased items.

**How to obtain that purchased item?**

The user must request `Purchase that item again`, observes the error `You already own this item` within the Google Billing BottomSheet and then re-run the app.

Only after that `dancing with a fire` the app retrieves purchased item within the `billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(params: QueryPurchasesParams)` result.

How to obtain a list of purchases items within the `queryPurchasesAsync(...)` function without dancing with a fire?

The app is serverless.

---

Requesting the  `billingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(...)` function before querying purchases did not help as well.